How does someone flying with windsuit sound like if he talks to the camera?
How does someone flying with windsuit sound like if he talks to the camera?
Appreciate your help guys.
Main track dry? Secondary track with reverb shifted? Mids only?

The key sound you need to factor in is wind noise. Think about putting your head out the car window at 100mph.
